# Getting the correct post ID in Wordpress query loop

Tags: loop, query, id

I'm trying to add custom field values inside a Wordpress query loop, so that I can have a list of titles, excerpts, and extras like start ratings in the loop results. I want to use something like `echo get_post_meta( $post_id, $key )` for this but nothing shows up.

I realised that's because the `$post_id` these commands are seeing is the ID of the page on which the query loop appears, not the ID of the posts that are the loop results.

I verified this by echoing `$post->ID`, `get_the_ID()`, or `get_queried_object_id()` within the loop  elements, which all return the ID of the page post, not the found posts.

I'm doing all this within the block editor and running the php via a snippet plugin.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the Query Loop block available in the editor?

Comment: Yes. I've added a screenshot to clarify.